# mod_rewrite causes 500 server error/Fails/works partially

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to do a permanent redirect from my old design ([www.your-translations.com](http://www.your-translations.com)) to my new design at [www.your-translations.com/_YT](http://www.your-translations.com/_YT).

In the process, the urls have to change from this format:

> www.your-translations.com/**my_page.php**

to this format:

> www.your-translations.com/_YT/**index.php?pge=my_page**

I have made many attempts so far, the latest of which is:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}    ^.*your\-translations.com.*$    [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/([^/]*)\.php $1/_YT/index.php?pge=$2 [R=302]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^your-translations.com [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.your-translations.com/$1 [R=302,L]
```

This is one of my better tries in that it apparently does almost nothing (previous tries have resulted in 505 errors and infinite loops). The rewriting of URLs to "www." works properly.

I have tested the regex in different regex testers and it seems to do what I expect it to do.

Can someone explain what I am doing wrong?

1. WHAT exactly is the pattern applied to? Is it what is matched by the RewriteCond? The URI as I typed it in? The relative path? The actual path on the server?

Is there any way to display the string before I try to match it?

1. Several suggestions found in tutorials result in infinite loops on my server. Do all versions work the same way?

Unfortunately, the webhost technical support doesn't seem to know anything about mod_rewrite, so I can't expect any help from them.

According to my FTP log, I have already made about 80 attempts and I could really use a hand here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to some explanations from [webmasterworld](http://www.webmasterworld.com/apache/4560719.htm), I was able to fix my mod_rewrite code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^your-translations.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.your-translations.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !="^.*?/.*" 
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.php$ http://www.your-translations.com/_YT/index.php?pge=$1 [R=302,L]
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.your-translations.com/_YT/ [R=302,L]
```

This seems to work correctly so far (touching wood). Thanks Servant for your help.

Answer (score 1):

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^your-translations\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/_YT/([a-z0-9-_]+)\.php$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([a-z0-9-_]+)\.php$
RewriteRule ^(.*) /_YT/index.php?pge=%1 [QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.your-translations\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/_YT/([a-z0-9-_]+)\.php$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([a-z0-9-_]+)\.php$
RewriteRule ^(.*) /_YT/index.php?pge=%1 [QSA]
```

In RewriteCond, you must type a backslash before a dot and not before dash, because a dot in .htaccess means any character, so you need bslash to call is as dot. Sorry, I'm in mobile, so I couldn't explain more, but feel free to ask what you want to know about the code.

Comment: Thanks, but it's not quite there: The home page www.your-translations.com is redirected, but the URL displayed doesn't change (I have added /_YT to the rewrite rule) an dthe css & js files all return 404. Inside pages like yt.com/my_page.php are not redirected at all.

Comment: nope. Doesn't work. I have an idea that feels wrong, but I don't see any actual downside: What if I replaced every page of my old website with a php redirect script to the proper page? This feels very wrong but on the other hand it would probably be faster to do at this point and a lot safer. Is there any problem I haven't thought of?

Comment: What's your real website? And what's the real wildcard web addresses you want to rewrite? And the real addresses that you want to copy? Note, I've edited the code on the main answer.

Comment: The info in this post is all real. My website is www.your-translations.com. The new design is in the /_YT/ folder.

Comment: Sorry, I just tried the code in the updated answer and it still doesn't work.

Comment: You said, you want to redirect www.your-translations.com to www.your-translations.com/_YT Now, do you want to rewrite www.your-translations.com/_YT/index.php?pge=my_page to www.your-translations.com/my_page.php or to rewrite www.your-translations.com/my_page.php to www.your-translations.com/_YT/index.php?pge=my_page or REDIRECT?

Comment: I want to rewrite www.your-translations.com/my_page.php to www.your-translations.com/_YT/index.php?pge=my_page. Obviously, all other files called by the new design (CSS/JS/Etc.) must have paths relative to /_YT/ and not from the root.

Comment: Wew.. Now, try to check the new one.

Comment: Still not working. Same results as the very first attempt actually. Seriously, I know it's butt ugly, but is there any downside to redirecting each page in PHP?

Comment: What do you mean, downside to redirecting each page in PHP? Have you ever tried to run my code, just itself? Of course including `Options +FollowSymlinks` and `RewriteEngine on`. I do not know why the new one didn't work..

Comment: Yes, I have tried to run your code by itself, and of course, with Options +F and the Rewrite engine on. I also tried to add RewriteBase / or RewriteBase /_YT or RewriteBase /_YT/. I also tried to use ^(.+)\.php$ and many other variations (28 new attempts). Nothing works (same behavior described in first comment). What I mean by redirecting each page in php is to open each existing page in the old site and replacing the whole content with a php redirect header() as explained here: http://www.phpjunkyard.com/tutorials/php-redirect.php.

Comment: I didn't have experience on PHP redirect. I've edited the code again. Try to check if it would work. I'd review it, and for me, the code is fine.

Comment: Sorry, it still doesn't work. Thanks a lot for your willingness to help

Comment: Try to contact your web hosting provider why that `.htaccess` code didn't work. Maybe the problem is in the configuration of the Apache HTTP server.

Comment: :)  You said, you want to rewrite, but you've redirected it. Just add an `[R]` flag into rewrite condition to redirect.